# CSS. 3 columns layout with fixed-positioned side columns

Tags: css, overflow, html, css-position

I've got a problem with this design. Example here:
 http://zxc.pp.ua/test/05.htm OR http://jsfiddle.net/SkeLLLa/qQRpx/

If browser's window width is less than 1000px (wrapper size) the scroll appears, and when I drag it to the right, center column goes under left column.

How can I set "minimum margin" for center element? Or if you know alternative ways to implement such layout, please tell me.

Comment: So, what do you want to happen in this case instead of the column overlap?

Comment: Somthing like in this tutorial: http://buildinternet.com/2009/10/purely-css-faking-minimum-margins/

or with css3 selector @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { <other css> }

Answer (score 0):

you've fixed positioned the other columns, therefore it wont show if it's loaded off screen or needs to be scrolled to as it doesn't move. either remove the fixed position or decrease the wrapper size.

Answer (score 0):

First of all [read this](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) I have been doing CSS for awhile and I always have to go reference it.  [Try this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) for the min width.  Let me know if you are still having trouble, maybe I don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: actually yeah dude read that first link and start over... you have all three columns contained within your 'center' column.  This would be easier for me to start from scratch.  Download firebug or use the developer tools in Chrome.  They will be life savers.

Comment: I've read first link sevral times. Nesting all in central column not fix this issue. Min-width also doesn't affect on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options.

To achieve the same effect, you could create a background image with the column colors you want and set the wrapper background with this image, giving the allusion to three columns the whole way down.

You can also set three columns in a wrapper. Set wrapper to overflow:hidden. Give each of the floated columns a bottom padding of 2000px and a negative margin of 2000px. This will stretch the columns to the bottom of the wrapper div without creating extra scroll.

You could also check out CSS 3 column holy grail: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm

Comment: May be we've got missunderstanding... I've said about horisontal scroll, that "hides" central column under left. I don't need to stretch left & right columns...

Holy grail tutorials are good, but not in this case. I have 2 fix-posittioned columns and I need them to be always visible to user, because central column is "endless" (like goolge+ news feed, etc.)